# create a relation in Cypher to match between nodes one per one only

Tags: neo4j

in Neo4j

if i have s:school o:office each label of them have 100 nodes

i need to create a relation in Cypher to match between one of school and only one of office that share the same ID

how to find out this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more detail would be useful, but if you have a property of each side you can `MATCH` and `CREATE` like this:

```
MATCH (school:School), (office:Office)
WHERE school.property = office.property
CREATE (school)-[:YOUR_RELATIONSHIP_TYPE]->(office)
```

If you're using Neo4j 2.3.x you'll probably get a warning about cartesian products.  It shouldn't be a big deal with only 100 nodes each, but for larger datasets this should be more efficient:

```
MATCH (school:School)
WITH school, school.property AS property
MATCH (office:Office {property: property})
CREATE (school)-[:YOUR_RELATIONSHIP_TYPE]->(office)
```

Of course you should make sure there is an index or a constraint on `Office(property)`